# Network probing on IPv6

Tags: networking, udp, ipv6, detect, probe

I am familiar using IPv4 broadcast of UDP packets as a technique for probing the network looking for servers running a given service. I.E. the broadcast packet is sent out on a given port and the listening servers can reply to this packet and the reply will allow the client to know the ip addresses of the available servers.

I am wondering what the recommended accepted technique is for doing the same type of network probing for IPv6. I have not done much with IPv6 but would like to make my new application compatible with it (for future proofing). I know I cannot use broadcast packets in the same way as IPv4 allow because this feature is taken out of IPv6. I would expect there must be another way to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the link local all nodes multicast address ff02::1 to achieve the same result

Comment: Be sure to use the IPV6_MULTICAST_IF socket option to specify the sending interface.